# Weird operator and wavefunctions

Tags: wavefunction, operators

How can one show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^*(x)(d/dx+\tanh x)(-d/dx+\tanh x)\psi(x) dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |(d/dx+\tanh x)\psi(x)|^2 dx$, where $\psi$ is normalized?

Comment: The equation in the question(v1) contains a sign error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tanh(x) is a Hermitian operator, whereas d/dx is an anti-Hermitian one.

Hermitian operator may be applied to the ψ∗ without the change, the anti-Hermitian changes the sign.

**Edit:**

How does one know if a specific operator is Hermitian?

The operator `d/dx + tanh(x)` may be presented as a sum of two operators: `d/dx` and `tanh(x)`.

Let's start with the former: `tanh(x)` It's a multiplicative operator. Means it multiplies the function ψ(x) by another function. Since within the multiplication we are free to reorder multipliers the following holds:

`ψ∗ (tanhx ψ) = (tanhx ψ∗) ψ`

And, since `tanhx` is a real function - we may also rewrite it this way:

`ψ∗ (tanhx ψ) = (tanhx ψ)∗ ψ`

This means that the operator `tanhx` may be applied to either the function itself, or to its conjugate, without any difference. Hence this operator is Hermitian.

Now let's see what happens with `d/dx`.

`I [ ψ∗ (d/dx) ψ dx] = I [ ψ∗ dψ ] = Boundary [ ψ∗ ψ ] - I [ dψ∗ ψ ]`

Integrating by part we're left with a boundary term and another integral. The boundary term vanishes since ψ goes to zero at +/- infinity. (BTW we didn't use the fact that ψ is normalized to 1).

Hence:

`I [ ψ∗ {(d/dx) ψ} dx] =  - I [ dψ∗ ψ ] = - I [ {(d/dx)ψ}* ψ dx ]`

`I [ ψ∗ {(d/dx) ψ} dx] =  I [ {(-d/dx)ψ}* ψ dx ]`

This means that if the operator `(d/dx)` is transferred to the conjugate part of the integral - its sign should be changed. Such an operator is anti-Hermitian.

P.S. You should remember those special cases:

- multiplication by a real function is a Hermitian operator.
- multiplication by an imaginary function is an anti-Hermitian operator.
- Derivative operators are either Hermitian or anti-Hermitian, depends on the order of the derivative. 1st derivative - anti-Hermitian, 2nd derivative - Hermitian. And so on.

P.P.S.

You should also know that the momentum operator is defined as `hbar/i d/dx` (in 1 dimension). It's Hermitian because it consists of a `d/dx` and `i`. Both are anti-Hermitian.

Comment: How does one know that which operators are hermintian?

Comment: @Raj do integration by parts on $\int\psi^*(x)\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x)dx=-\int\frac{d}{dx}(\psi^*(x))\psi(x)dx$. For "multiplication by $\tanh(x)$", you can just "move it around inside the integral sign", so we can say that it acts on $\psi(x)$ or $\psi^*(x)$ without any change of sign. Hence, $\frac{d}{dx}$ is anti-Hermitian, "multiplication by $\tanh(x)$ " is Hermitian.